# while loop is changing every object and not iterating through

Tags: c++, vector, matrix-multiplication

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <list>

using namespace std;

// format for a Matrix
char* Matrix::printM(){
    char* s = new char[5000*1024];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i < this->dimension.rows;i++){
        int j;
        for(j=0;j< this->dimension.columns;j++){
            Vector* tmp = this->columns[j];
            int x = this->dimension.columns - 1;
            if(j == 0){
                char buffer[500];
                //it0oa(v->coordinate[i],buffer,sizeof(int));
                snprintf(buffer,5000,"%f",tmp->coordinate[i]);
                strncat(s,"|", 1+ strlen(s));
                strncat(s,buffer, strlen(s) + strlen(buffer));
                strncat(s,",",strlen(s) + 1);
            }else if(j == x){
                char buffer[500];
                snprintf(buffer,5000,"%f",tmp->coordinate[i]);
                strncat(s,buffer,strlen(s) + strlen(buffer));
                strncat(s,"|\n",strlen(s)+2);
            }else{
                char buffer[500];
                snprintf(buffer,5000,"%f",tmp->coordinate[i]);
                strncat(s,buffer,strlen(s) + strlen(buffer));
                strncat(s,",",strlen(s) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return s;
}
Matrix::Matrix(int di,int de){
    this->dimension.rows =de;
    this->dimension.columns =di;
    this->columns.assign(di,new Vector(de));
}
Matrix::Matrix(std::vector<Vector*> v, int di){
    this->dimension.columns = v.size();
    this->columns = v;
    int it;
    this->dimension.rows = v[0]->dimension;
}
Matrix& Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& v){
    Matrix* mt = new Matrix(this->dimension.columns,6);
    mt->dimension = this->dimension;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i< mt->dimension.columns;i++){
        //mt->columns.push_back(&(*this->columns[i] + *v.columns[i]));
        mt->columns[i] = &(*this->columns[i] + *v.columns[i]);
        printf("%s\n",mt->columns[0]->printV());
    }
    return *mt;
}
Matrix& Matrix::operator-(const Matrix& v){
    Matrix* mt = new Matrix(this->dimension.columns,7);
    mt->dimension = this->dimension;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i< mt->dimension.columns;i++){
        //mt->columns.push_back(&(*this->columns[i] + *v.columns[i]));
        mt->columns[i] = &(*this->columns[i] - *v.columns[i]);
        printf("%s\n",mt->columns[0]->printV());
    }
    return *mt;
}
Matrix& Matrix::operator*(const double& v){
    Matrix* mt = new Matrix(this->dimension.columns,7);
    mt->dimension = this->dimension;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i< mt->dimension.columns;i++){
        //mt->columns.push_back(&(*this->columns[i] + *v.columns[i]));
        mt->columns[i] = &(*this->columns[i] * v);
        //printf("%s\n",mt->columns[0]->printV());
    }
    return *mt;
}
std::vector<Vector*> Matrix::row_equiv(Matrix* m){
    std::list<Vector*> result;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i< m->dimension.rows;i++){
        std::list<double> lists;
        lists.push_back(m->dimension.columns);
        int j;
        for(j=0;j< m->dimension.columns;j++){
            Vector* tmp = m->columns[j];
            lists.push_back(tmp->coordinate[i]);
        }
        j=0;
        //std::initializer_list<double> list_h = lists;
        Vector* tmp = new Vector(lists);
        result.push_back(tmp);

    }
    std::vector<Vector*> x{std::begin(result),std::end(result)};
    return x;
}
Matrix* Matrix::transpose(){
    std::vector<Vector*> b = row_equiv(this);
    Matrix* mt = new Matrix(b,this->dimension.rows);
    return mt;
}
Matrix* Matrix::upperTriangular(){
    std::vector<Vector*> tmp = row_equiv(this);
    if(this->is_square()){
        int j;
        for(j=0;j<this->dimension.columns;j++){
            double pivot = tmp[j]->coordinate[j];
            int i;
            for(i=j+1;i<this->dimension.rows;i++){
                tmp[i] = &((*tmp[i]) - (*tmp[j] * (tmp[i]->coordinate[j]/pivot)));
            }

        }
    }else if(this->dimension.rows > this->dimension.columns){
        //printf("Hello world,\n");
        int j;
        for(j=0;j<this->dimension.columns;j++){
            double pivot = tmp[j]->coordinate[j];
            printf("%f\n",pivot);
            int i;
            for(i=j+1;i< this->dimension.rows;i++){
                tmp[i] = &((*tmp[i]) + (*tmp[j] * (tmp[i]->coordinate[j]/-1*pivot)));
                    printf(" The vector is %s\n",tmp[i]->printV());
            }

        }
    }else if(this->dimension.rows < this->dimension.columns){
        printf("Not Hello World!");
    }

    Matrix* result = new Matrix(tmp,this->dimension.rows);
    return result->transpose();
}
// This is supposed to give me the multiplication of matrices but it's not working right now.
Matrix& Matrix::operator*(const Matrix& v){

    if(this->dimension.columns == v.dimension.rows){
        Matrix* mt  = new Matrix(v.dimension.columns,this->dimension.rows);
        mt->dimension.rows = this->dimension.rows;
        std::vector<Vector*> tmp = row_equiv(this);
        std::vector<Vector* > result(v.dimension.columns, new Vector(this->dimension.rows));
        for(auto i =0; i < tmp.size();i++){ //for each rows of the first matrix
            int j =0;
            while(j< this->dimension.columns){ //for each columns of the second matrix
                //printf("%f and %f\n",tmp[i]->dimension,this->columns[j]->dimension);
                //double x = *tmp[i] * *v.columns[j];
                //printf("%f\n",x);
                //mt->columns[j]->coordinate[i] = (*tmp[i] * *v.columns[j]); // This line is giving me problems.
                //printf("THis is after the code\n");
                result[j]->coordinate[i] = (*tmp[i] * *v.columns[j]);
                printf("%s and %s %f and %s %s an j = %d\n",tmp[i]->printV(),v.columns[j]->printV(),result[j]->coordinate[i],result[j]->printV(),result[0]->printV(),j);
                j++;
            }
            printf("%s\n",result[0]->printV());
        }
        return *mt;
    }
    Matrix* mt = new Matrix(3,2);
    return *mt;
}
```

The problem is with this piece of code

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator*(const Matrix& v){

if(this->dimension.columns == v.dimension.rows){
    Matrix* mt  = new Matrix(v.dimension.columns,this->dimension.rows);
    mt->dimension.rows = this->dimension.rows;
    std::vector<Vector*> tmp = row_equiv(this);
    std::vector<Vector* > result(v.dimension.columns, new Vector(this->dimension.rows));
    for(auto i =0; i < tmp.size();i++){ //for each rows of the first matrix
        int j =0;
        while(j< this->dimension.columns){ //for each columns of the second matrix
            //printf("%f and %f\n",tmp[i]->dimension,this->columns[j]->dimension);
            //double x = *tmp[i] * *v.columns[j];
            //printf("%f\n",x);
            //mt->columns[j]->coordinate[i] = (*tmp[i] * *v.columns[j]); // This line is giving me problems.
            //printf("THis is after the code\n");
            result[j]->coordinate[i] = (*tmp[i] * *v.columns[j]);
            printf("%s and %s %f and %s %s an j = %d\n",tmp[i]->printV(),v.columns[j]->printV(),result[j]->coordinate[i],result[j]->printV(),result[0]->printV(),j);
            j++;
        }
        printf("%s\n",result[0]->printV());
    }
    return *mt;
}
    Matrix* mt = new Matrix(3,2);
    return *mt;
}
```

The function is supposed to multiply 2 matrices together. 
This line is changing `result[0]` every time it runs and I don't know why. result is a vector of  Vector* and the while loop is supposed to iterate through the Vector of the vector(list) and changing the ith component but every time the loop goes through it changes the previous Vector.

```
 result[j]->coordinate[i] = (*tmp[i] * *v.columns[j])
```

This is the implementation :

```
for(auto i=0; i < this->dimension.rows;i++){
            for(auto j=0; j<v.dimension.columns;j++){
                for(auto k=0; k< this->dimension.rows;k++){
                    result[j]->coordinate[i] += this->columns[i]->coordinate[k] * v.columns[k]->coordinate[j];
                    printf("j = %d, %s and %s\n",j,result[j]->printV(), result[0]->printV());
                }
            }
        }
```

When j = 1, result[0] also changes and i don't know why. This is the ouput .

```
j = 0, <2.000000,0.000000> and <2.000000,0.000000>
j = 0, <2.000000,0.000000> and <2.000000,0.000000>
j = 1, <2.000000,0.000000> and <2.000000,0.000000>
j = 1, <1.000000,0.000000> and <1.000000,0.000000>
j = 2, <1.000000,0.000000> and <1.000000,0.000000>
j = 2, <1.000000,0.000000> and <1.000000,0.000000>
j = 0, <1.000000,-1.000000> and <1.000000,-1.000000>
j = 0, <1.000000,-1.000000> and <1.000000,-1.000000>
j = 1, <1.000000,-1.000000> and <1.000000,-1.000000>
j = 1, <1.000000,1.000000> and <1.000000,1.000000>
j = 2, <1.000000,1.000000> and <1.000000,1.000000>
j = 2, <1.000000,1.000000> and <1.000000,1.000000>
```

Comment: where is printV function ??

Comment: `strncat(s` causes UB, `strncat` requires a string to start with

Comment: `snprintf` is called with length argument greater than the buffer size (although unlikely to overflow in this particular case)

Comment: `strncat` 3rd argument is incorrect in every call; all of those could be `strcat` instead (although `snprintf` would be more efficient and tidier)

Comment: `operator*` (and the other operators) should return by value; the way you have done it now is conducive to memory leaks. Don't use `new` at all here

Comment: Don't use `strncat` until you've read its documentation and understood it. It is a very specialized function, and almost certainly does **not** do what you want. In particular,it is **not** a drop-in "safe" replacement for `strcat`.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication is defined differently. It requires 3 nested for loops - not just two:

For every pair `(i,j)`, you need to iterate over all values of `k`, and do the following pseudocode:

```
result = zeros(a.rows,b.cols)
for i = 0:a.rows-1
   for j = 0:b.cols-1
      for k = 0:a.cols-1
         result(i,j) += a(i,k) * b(k,j)
```

Comment: I've edit the original post to implement your pseudocode. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I had a mistake. Edited my post now.

Comment: it's still giving the same problem which is that the first coordinate of the vector result[0] is changing.

Comment: I think you confused result(i,j) with result(j,i)

Comment: it seems to happen when j = 1 and k = 1. result(i,j) means ith row with jth columns?

Comment: Correct. And we are not allowed to switch roles between rows and columns. Check that all of your matrix references are exactly as the pseudocode says - first index is the row, second is the column.

Comment: This is the problem. gdb output `result[0]->printV() = 0x61e960 "<2.000000,0.000000>"` `result[1]->printV() = 0x61f170 "<2.000000,0.000000>"`  `result[2]->printV() = 0x61f980 "<2.000000,0.000000>"`. This is when `j=0`, it's changing every element in the vector result.